Problemas con libreria html2canvas y jspdf
Les comento el prolema que tengo con estas librerias, estamos trabajando con un cotizador online y al momento de compartir necesitamos que una de las opciones sea en pdf, el problema es que siempre se genera una hoja demás y si se la logramos sacar, se rompe el pdf. Alguien sabe como se puede llegar a solucionar? o si conocen otra librería?
esta es la porción de código de la funcion que utilizo para generar el pdf
generatePDF() {
  const element = this.contentToCapture.nativeElement;

  const opt = {
    margin: [0.6, 0.5],
    filename: `presupuesto${this.presupuesto.idpresupuesto}.pdf`,
    image: { type: 'jpeg', quality: 0.98 },
      html2canvas: { scale: 2 },
      jsPDF: { unit: 'in', format: 'a4', orientation: 'portrait' },
      pagebreak: { mode: ['avoid-all', 'css', 'legacy' ] },
      
  };

  html2pdf().from(element).set(opt).save();
}

al modificar el  pagebreak: { mode: ['avoid-all'] }, tiene un problema con respecto a la renderización de el pdf  

¿Que pasa si solo lo configuras con  pagebreak: { mode: 'avoid-all'}?

@Marcos saca la hoja en blanco, pero tiene un problema de renderización. Lo pongo en la descripción

¿Tenes la posibilidad de modificar ese HTML?

Yo lo solucione usando breakInside: "avoid-page" en el div que no quiero que se corte espero te sirva también.
<div style={{ breakInside: "avoid-page" }}> </div>

